# Update a span when a select dropdown is made using ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, drop-down-menu

I am attempting to code the following script using jquery / ajax / php.
What happens is the php pulls all the records from the database and puts them into a select dropdown. When I select an item from the dropdown ajax pulls the price from the database and adds it into the span called priceeach1 . Well thats what its supposed to do, but my jquery is useless :-S .
The stockID comes from the select box value.

```
            <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
        $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#stock1').on('change', function (){

        var newValue1 = $.getJSON('select2.php', {stockID: $(this).val()}, function(data){
                    var options = '';
                   for (var x = 0; x < data.length; x++) { 
    options += data[x]['priceeach']; 
    }
     $('#priceeach1').text( options);
                });
            });
        });
        </script>
```

The HTML :

```
Price Each : &pound;<span id="priceeach1"></span>
```

The select2.php :

```
            <?php include 'connectmysqli.php'; ?>
    <?php
    $id = $_GET['stockID'];
    $sql = 'SELECT * FROM stock WHERE stockID = ' . (int)$id;
    $result = $db->query($sql);

    $json = array();
    while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
      $json[] = array(
        'priceeach' => $row['priceeach'],
      );
    }
    echo json_encode($json);

    ?>
```

EDIT >> Ok I have now updated the code with the latest edits, this now WORKS.....apart from an odd problem......If I select the first or last item in the list no price is displayed, anything in between appears just fine..........

Comment: check your variable `newValue1`'s value using console, you'll have a surprise or not if you expect it to be a deferred object

Comment: it's not clear what you're trying to do, but you override `options` value in each iteration and to make things worse... you never use that var but use instead `newValue1` that is never declared or assigned.

Comment: @ClaudioRedi OP has edited is POST, make it not better though

Comment: BTW, this code doesn't make sense at all

Comment: So, what is supposed to be 'newValue1' ???

Comment: Try to use this snipt: `for (var x = 0; x < data.length; x++) {
                    options += data[x]['priceeach'];
                }
                $('#priceeach1').text( options);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this,

```
   var options = [];
   for (var x = 0; x < data.length; x++) {
          options = data[x]['priceeach'];
   }
   $('#priceeach1').text(options.join(','));
```

Comment: check in `console`, before trying the above by using, `console.log(data);`

Comment: Ok I have now updated the code with the latest edits, this now WORKS.....apart from an odd problem......If I select the first or last item in the list no price is displayed, anything in between appears just fine..........

Comment: For that `change` check the value of `drop down element`. What post data send in your php page as `stockID`? May be it will blank.

Comment: Checked that and its a valid stockID thats being sent

Answer (score 0):

It should be like this you have to store price in the array `options[]` instead of `option` and then `join` them by any separator

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
    $(document).ready(function(){
    $('#stock').on('change', function (){

    var newValue1 = $.getJSON('select2.php', {stockID: $(this).val()}, function(data){
                var options = '';
                for (var x = 0; x < data.length; x++) {
                    options[x] = data[x]['priceeach'];
                }
                $('#priceeach1').text(options.join(','));
            });
        });
    });
    </script>
```

Comment: I get an error at this line when I paste this into dreamweaver :    options[] = data[x]['priceeach'];

Comment: Thanks for the edit, the error has gone away, but still doesnt retrieve any price

Comment: what is in your data `console.log(data)` in request

Comment: How do I view that, as I am using chrome, and when I click developer tools and console, nothing shows up.

Comment: in chrome use network panel and see what this request gives the response

Comment: Ok I have now updated the code with the latest edits, this now WORKS.....apart from an odd problem......If I select the first or last item in the list no price is displayed, anything in between appears just fine..........

Answer (score 0):

You have to parse your JSON data to actual JSON Object before iterating it.

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
    $(document).ready(function(){
    $('#stock').on('change', function (){

    var newValue1 = $.getJSON('select2.php', {stockID: $(this).val()}, function(data){
                var jsonParsed = JSON.parse(data);
                var options = '';
                for (var x = 0; x < jsonParsed.length; x++) {
                    options[] = jsonParsed[x]['priceeach'];
                }
                $('#priceeach1').text(options.join(','));
            });
        });
    });
    </script>
```

Comment: When I paste this into Dreamweaver I get an error at this line :   options[] = jsonParsed[x]['priceeach'];

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this snipt:

```
for (var x = 0; x < data.length; x++) { 
options += data[x]['priceeach']; 
}
 $('#priceeach1').text( options);
```

Comment: you must be check first data array contain elements or empty?

Comment: `for (var x = 0; x < data.length; x++) { alert(data[x]['priceeach']);
options += data[x]['priceeach']; 
}`

Comment: you can use alert() function